# How to use onNavigationStateChange from react-navigation in react-native-router-flux?

Tags: react-native

I was wondering if react-native-router-flux has react-navigation as it's dependencies, is there a way to hack into it's code and bring out something like `onNavigationStateChange`, and use it with `rnrf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about "onStateChange" in Router. I am using it for closing keyboard if it is open in case of any tab or scene. Hope it'll help

```
import { Router } from 'react-native-router-flux'

 <Router
   onStateChange={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
   backAndroidHandler={this.backAction}>

{my all scenes}
</Router>
```